# Manipulating session file

Tags: php, session

So I want to know, is it very bad to manipulate session files. What bad things I have to expect for doing that?

In my website everytime user logs in, he gets session id, and that ID is writen to DB. And every time when user logs out I delete that session id from DB and file system and regenerate new one for guest mode.

So how bad is: `@unlink(session_save_path().'/sess_'.$old_sess);`

Thank you.

Comment: Session files should be deleted automatically by PHP, i.e., you should NOT do that from scripts. Also, I would advise to avoid using `@`, as it is PITA to debug such code, when you see nothing more than a blank screen.

Comment: Use `@` or not, depends on situation. I prefer use `@` to handle file manipulation errors by my self.

Comment: It indeed depends on situation, though, as I wrote, it is PITA to debug such code. I've had situation when the only thing I saw was [WSOD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_screen_of_death#PHP_web_applications) without anything in error log even with error reporting being set to maximum - just because `@` was used with function that caused fatal error. I don't even know how many hours admins wasted because of that before calling me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Session data may not always be on disk(you can store session data in memcache or shared memory)

Why bother deleting the file in the first place?

http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-probability can be tuned to do what you want

Comment: Good idea. I will use Redis for handling sessions, when 2.4 version will come out.

Answer (score 0):

Since you write the session ids in a database anyway, you should write your own session handler that doesn't depend on the file system. Otherwise - yes, it is a bad idea.